# Redis Performance Optimization - Does a slave's replication take as much compute resources as being a master?

Tags: performance, redis, performance-tuning

I have the need for two desperate Redis Instances.

One's job is mostly as a session store (currently deployed), the others role will be as an usage statistics depot. Assume my servers are single-threaded (so just adding more instances will not be a performance boon)

Currently, I am "wasting" a lot of computing resources for high availability purposes, I am wondering if this can be remedied.

My purposed architecture would be as follows (Assume a working three server sentinel configuration):

```
+----+    +----+
| Ma |    | Mb |
| Rb |    | Ra |
+----+    +----+

     M = Master
     R = Slave
+----+
|    | = Physical Server
+----+
```

If replication takes as much computational resources as processing requests as master, then this configuration will not do me much good on a single cpu server.

I am doing basic command, stringget, stringset, set adds, ect. Obviously, performance will be impacted if there is down time on a server, but that is not the usual case. Will this configuration let me increase throughput while utilizing more of my hardware?

---

Edit: There doesn't seem to be a lot of Redis activity on this site, can someone suggest a better site to migrate this question to?